# strange cout behaviour

Tags: c++, cout

I compiled on Ubuntu a program that was developed for (and works on) Windows.  On Ubuntu, I see this code:

```
string s = values_[9];
cout << s << endl;
cout << s << "x\n";
```

producing this output:

```
high
xigh
```

The expected output for the second line is "highx".  I know that the value of values_[9] is originally read from a file (written on Windows).  Printing other strings seems to work normally.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run the command with its output piped through `cat -A`.  Probably either the value of `s`, or the output produced by `endl` is giving you a `'\r'` character, which typically sends the cursor back to the beginning of the line.

EDIT: On further thought, the stray `'\r'` is almost certainly in `s`, not in the output produced by `endl`.  I had thought there might be some funny locale stuff going on, but having `s` equal to `"high\r"` explains the symptoms.

EDIT2: If your system doesn't have `cat -A` (it's a GNU extension), try `cat -v` or, if you're desperate, `od -c`.

Comment: +1 (add "But not on Windows, hence the disparate observations.")

Comment: Actually, `\r'` does send the cursor to the beginning of the line on Windows (depending on where you write it, I suppose, but it works that way in a `cmd` window).  The difference is that Windows uses '"\r\n"' as a line terminator in text files, whereas Unix uses `"\n"`.  Well-behaved software probably won't produce isolated `'\r'` characters on either system.

Comment: OK, but according to the output there _is_ an isolated `\r` (otherwise the `x` would be on its own line).

Comment: As I said, "Well-behaved software" and "probably".  8-)}

Comment: OK, but then this is obviously not "well-behaved software" and so the disparate observations must be due to something else! :)

Comment: Oh, I'm with you. The `\r` could be stripped (read: discarded as part of the line delimiter) during read on Windows, but not under Linux, leaving it isolated at the end of the text.

Comment: And, yes, `endl` is **defined** to be a `flush` followed by `\n`. On all platforms.

Comment: There's no `cat -A` on the Mac (Snow Leopard) either.  Gotta love the GNU extensions....

Comment: @Ray: They try `cat -v`, or, if you're desperate, `od -c`.  (Or install GNU coreutils if you're so inclined.)

Comment: @Tomalak: I thought it was `\n` followed by `flush`.  But a '`\n'` character can be translated when written to a text stream; on Windows, `std::cout << "\n"` will write a CR and an LF.

Comment: @Keith: Er, yes, that way around. It _can_ be translated by the underlying buffer, but that would only occur on a system that will handle the `\r` properly!

Comment: @Tomolak: Yes, but it's not uncommon for text files to be copied from Windows to Unix/Linux systems without being translated.  That's one of a plethora of possible explanation for how the `'\r'` got into `values_[9]`.  (Actually, we have no idea where it came from.)

Answer (score 4):

The string you're printing has a carriage return `'\r'` in it.  What's happening is that you're printing `high`, then the carriage return, which puts the cursor back on the start of the line.  Then, when you print the `x`, it overwrites the first letter on the line.

You should either remove the carriage return from the source file (e.g. with [`dos2unix(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) or many other options), or change your code to strip the carriage return after reading the file in.

Answer (score 3):

What is probably happening, is that there is a `\r` in `values_[9]`.